# Ubuntu apt not working

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Whenever I try to install something using apt on Ubuntu linux(version 20.04.1 LTS), I keep getting this error saying :

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try to run  `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get this error:

```
buntu@ubuntu1:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-mutter-6 gnome-startup-applications humanity-icon-theme
  libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libmozjs-68-0 libroken18-heimdal
  libwind0-heimdal session-migration ubuntu-mono
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1078 not to upgrade.
192 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,278 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,230 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 amd64 1.18.0-2+b1 [2,278 kB]
Fetched 2,278 kB in 1s (2,652 kB/s)                   
(Reading database ... 225910 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.18.0-2+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (1.18.0-2+b1) over (1.16.2-2.1ubun
tu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1
.0-0_1.18.0-2+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0'
, which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.16.2-1ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.18.0-2+b1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ubuntu@ubuntu1:~$
```

The thing is that the error seems to be pretty well documented online with a lot of solutions but none of them seem to work, I have been trying so many for the past 3 hours and none of them work so I decided to ask on here.

Something that is interesting is the output that I get when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` where I get this really long message :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu1:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                 
Fetched 214 kB in 1s (263 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
```

*This is only a small part of the output the console gives me as it is way too large to put on a stack exchange question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is removing `kali-rolling` from your `sources.list` because it will break your `apt` then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Next step, use `--force-overwrite` option to force installing the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.18.0-2+b1_amd64.deb
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```